# ResponsiveVoice blocked by CORS

Tags: javascript, cors, text-to-speech, responsivevoice

I try building a function that reads digits with defined delay between one another.

```
{
...
play : function (digits, delay = 500) {
  if (digits && digits.length > 0) {
    responsiveVoice.speak(digits[0], "Czech Female", {
      rate: 0.7,
      onend: () => setTimeout(() => {
        this.play(digits.splice(1), delay);
      }, delay)
    });
  }
}
```

`digits` is an array of digits and `delay` the delay in ms between digits.

The function works fine for some time but randomly it fails with following error in the console:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://texttospeech.responsivevoice.org/v1/text:synthesize?text=0&lang=cs&engine=g1&name=&pitch=0.5&rate=0.35&volume=1&key=XXXXXXXX&gender=female' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
> ResponsiveVoice audio could not be loaded. There is an issue connecting your browser to the API endpoint.
> GET https://texttospeech.responsivevoice.org/v1/text:synthesize?text=0&lang=cs&engine=g1&name=&pitch=0.5&rate=0.35&volume=1&key=XXXXXXXX&gender=female net::ERR_FAILED

Can anyone give me a hint what is wrong?

Comment: The server is blocking some of your requests…are you including all required headers etc?

Answer (score 3):

The library you are using doesn't seem to behave well when it comes to the character `0` (at least). I tested your code and it worked well for any other input.

Somehow, when inputting `0` to this library, it sends the request to the API as [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) instead of [`HTMLAudioElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement) (used for every working speech).

[image: console]

`XMLHttpRequest` has some restrictions when it comes to cross-domain requests (for more informations you can read about [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)), and the API doesn't seem to support `XMLHttpRequest` calls.

This is an inconsistency between the library and the API, I suspect a bug in the library related with truthy/falsy checks.

You should contact their support and report this bug.

**Edit:**

As written in the comments, it seems that there is a workaround that consists in adding a space before the digit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the meanwhile I have also discovered that the problem is with "0". A hacky workaround is adding ```" "+digits[0]``` to the code.

Comment: OK I'm adding this to the answer for future readers